# llamar metodo de relación desde un modelo pivot

Tags: laravel, eloquent

Tengo tres tablas:

- users
- roles
- states

La tabla users y roles se relacionan muchos a muchos a través de una tabla intermedia. Dicha tabla intermedia tiene entonces el user_id y el role_id, pero además contiene un state_id que representa el estado de la relación.

He declarado un modelo personalizado para representar dicha tabla intermedia. Cómo puedo hacer para obtener el estado de cada relación que tenga un usuario.

Algo como

```
$user=App\Models\User::first()->roles->first()->pivot->state
```

Nótese que lo que quiero hacer en este caso es extender la funcionalidad del modelo pivot para poder acceder a métodos de relación como si fuese un modelo cualquiera.

//Modelo Personalizado RoleUser

```
public function state()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(State::class, 'state_id');
}
```

A través de este método state() quisiera, una vez obtenidos los roles de un usuario, obtener el nombre de estado de dicho rol, bien sea ACTIVO ó INACTIVO

Comment: para poder mostrar el respectivo nombre de ese state_id en la relación. Es decir:ACTIVO ó INACTIVO.

Comment: el state es un método que se encuentra en el modelo personalizado RoleUser, que devuelve un BelongsTo(State::class)

Comment: ¿Alguna razón en específico por la que creaste un modelo para la tabla intermedia?, te lo pregunto para poder proceder con una respuesta además de que no es necesario tener dicho modelo

Comment: Si. De acuerdo a la documentación el pivot atributo sólo tendrá acceso a las claves foraneas de los modelos relacionados. Además de aquellos campos que declremos en el withPivot('campo_adicional_1', 'campo_adicional_2'). Entonces mi idea es extender esa limitación del atributo pivot y de acuerdo a la documentación eso se logra personalizando el pivot a través de un modelo.

Comment: Si, puede ser. Por eso estoy consultando. Puedo hacer uso del método WithPivot('state_id'), pero esto me da acceso al id del estado, más no al nombre del estado. Es lo que quiero lograr y no sé cómo hacerlo. O dicho de otra forma. Es posible obtenet el modelo estado que tiene la relación role - user, para acceder state->name ?

Comment: lo he intentado usando : 
    public function estado()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(State::class, 'state_id');
    } 
en el modelo pivot pero no funciona

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Considerando el escenario que expones veo 2 posibilidades de solución.

1. Mediante el query builder construimos una sentencia empleando *joins* que vinculen las tablas:

- users
- roles
- role_user
- states

  ```
   User::select(['users.name', 'role_name', 'states.id', 'state_name'])
       ->join('role_user', 'users.id', '=', 'role_user.user_id')
       ->join('roles', 'roles.id', '=', 'role_user.role_id')
       ->join('states', 'states.id', '=', 'role_user.role_id')
       ->where('users.id', $idUsuario)
       ->get();
  ```

  - Lo anterior te puede ayudar a devolver una colección del usuario con el o los roles asignados y el nombre del estado de cada una de estas relaciones.

2. Mediante las relaciones de Eloquent, teniendo en cuenta lo siguiente:

   - No usaremos un modelo para la tabla intermedia
   - Nuestra consulta inicial sería de esta forma:

     ```
     $usuarioRoles = User::with(['roles' => function($query) {
         $query->orderBy('state_id', 'DESC'); 
     }])->find($idUsuario);
     ```

     - Con esta query estamos obteniendo un objeto, con los datos del usuario así como una colección de 1  o N objetos conteniendo la información de cada rol asociado (**puede darse el caso de usuarios sin rol asignado, esta parte ya te la dejo a ti de investigar para establecer un eventual filtro**), toma nota que aquí estamos mandando los **`state_id`** de la tabla **`role_user`** ordenados de forma descedente.
   - Ahora procedemos con el siguiente código:

     ```
       $conjuntoKeysStates = [];

       foreach($usuarioRoles->roles as $valor) {
           array_push($conjuntoKeysStates, $valor->pivot->state_id);
       }

       $stateNames = State::select('state_name')
                           ->orderBy('id', 'DESC')
                           ->whereIn('id', $conjuntoKeysStates)
                           ->get();


       foreach($usuarioRoles->roles as $claveIndice => $usuarioConRol) {
           $usuarioConRol->state_name = $stateNames[$claveIndice]->state_name;
       }
     ```

     - Iniciamos declarando un array, en el cual almacenaremos las **pk** de cada state recuperado
     - Posterior mediante un ciclo foreach iteramos la colección de roles asociados al usuario consultado y en el array declarado en el paso anterior almacenamos los id de cada state a los cuales accedemos mediante **`pivot->state_id`**
     - Ahora podemos construir una consulta en el modelo **`State`** donde recuperemos de manera descedente por su id los names de cada state filtrándolos por medio de los ids del paso anterior
     - Ahora mediante un último ciclo foreach iteramos nuevamente la colección de roles y asignamos en cada objeto el name de cada state recuperado en la consulta anterior
     - Aquí ya puedes retornar a: **`$usuarioRoles`**
     - Observa que tanto al recuperar las llaves primarias de los states así como al ordenar dichas llaves en la consulta principal establecemos un ordenamiento, esto con la intención de que al momento de conjuntar todos los datos en la misma query haga sintonía entre los registros.

**Nota final**

Recomiendo pongas a prueba ambos casos y determines cual te funciona mejor, considera que la última query ofrece (*desde mi punto de vista*) una salida de datos mas clara y simple pues el usuario solo aparecerá una vez con su propia colección de roles y dentro ahora además del **`state_id`** saldrá el **nombre de dicho state.**

Comment: Justo lo que necesitaba. Me ha servido mucho tu código. Además de eso la explicación ha sido excepcional. Te felicito por eso. Lo he modificado un poco xq en el $stateNames me genera sólo dos indices, ya que sólo tengo dos estados posibles (ACTIVO O INACTIVO) y por eso  cuando utilizaba $stateNames[$claveIndice]->state_name en el tercer rol no hacía match el indice xq el $stateName sólo tiene dos indices. Eso lo resolví con esto:
 
$estadoRol = $stateNames->firstWhere('id', $usuarioConRol->pivot->state_id);

$usuarioConRol->state_name = $estadoRol->name;

Muchas gracias por tu tiempo!!